# Scala project stopped building due to aspectj.dtd error with aopMerge

Tags: scala, sbt

My project stopped working from one day to another, without any changes in the project. I'm suspecting one of the dependencies updated, but it's unclear from the error message.

```
[warn] Merging 'META-INF/aop.xml' with strategy 'aopMerge'
[error] org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: -//AspectJ//DTD//EN; systemId: http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 2; The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed.
```

The aopMerge strategy in my build.sbt is

```
val aopMerge: MergeStrategy = new MergeStrategy {
  val name = "aopMerge"
  import scala.xml._
  import scala.xml.dtd._

  def apply(tempDir: File, path: String, files: Seq[File]): Either[String, Seq[(File, String)]] = {
    val dt                         = DocType("aspectj", PublicID("-//AspectJ//DTD//EN", "https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd"), Nil)
    val file                       = MergeStrategy.createMergeTarget(tempDir, path)
    val xmls: Seq[Elem]            = files.map(XML.loadFile)
    val aspectsChildren: Seq[Node] = xmls.flatMap(_ \\ "aspectj" \ "aspects" \ "_")
    val weaverChildren: Seq[Node]  = xmls.flatMap(_ \\ "aspectj" \ "weaver" \ "_")
    val options: String            = xmls.map(x => (x \\ "aspectj" \ "weaver" \ "@options").text).mkString(" ").trim
    val weaverAttr                 = if (options.isEmpty) Null else new UnprefixedAttribute("options", options, Null)
    val aspects                    = new Elem(null, "aspects", Null, TopScope, false, aspectsChildren: _*)
    val weaver                     = new Elem(null, "weaver", weaverAttr, TopScope, false, weaverChildren: _*)
    val aspectj                    = new Elem(null, "aspectj", Null, TopScope, false, aspects, weaver)
    XML.save(file.toString, aspectj, "UTF-8", xmlDecl = false, dt)
    IO.append(file, IO.Newline.getBytes(IO.defaultCharset))
    Right(Seq(file -> path))
  }
}
```

I tried changing `http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd` into `https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd` based on a similar question on StackOverflow. Unfortunately, I'm getting the same error, even with `http://` instead of `https://`. *Note that I did run `sbt reload` after the change.*

How can I find out why this is happening? And what can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The workaround I used was generating a new file with the HTTPS url based on the files passed in `files: Seq[File])` parameter. Then changing `val xmls: Seq[Elem] = files.map(XML.loadFile)` to use this new files.

```
val xmls: Seq[Elem] = files.map(generateFileWithSecureDtdUrl).map(XML.loadFile)
```

with the following declared on build.sbt

```
def generateFileWithSecureDtdUrl(originalFile: File): File = {
val fixedFileName = originalFile.getPath + ".fixed"

val ps: PrintStream = new PrintStream(fixedFileName) {
  val originalFileSource: BufferedSource = Source.fromFile(originalFile)

  originalFileSource
    .getLines()
    .map { line =>
      if (line.contains("DOCTYPE") && line.contains("http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd"))
        line.replace("http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd", "https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd")
      else
        line
    }
    .foreach(line => write(line.getBytes("UTF8")))

  originalFileSource.close()
}

ps.close()

new File(fixedFileName) }
```